# How to test if two conditions in of a 2AFC (Two-alternative forced choice) task is different or not?

Tags: chi-squared-test

My situation is as follows: My 2AFC (Two-alternative forced choice) task yields data in the following form:
1. number of true positives
2. number of true negatives
3. number of false positives
4. number of false negatives

for each single condition of my task. I would like to be able to assert, that two conditions of my task do not differ significantly. The most crude way that I could come up with is to pool true positives/negatives and false positive/negatives so that I end up with the number of correct decisions and wrong decision and perform a binomial test between the two conditions (Chi^2 or exact fisher test), but I find that approach lacking as pooling can create wrong impressions. Can you tell me a better way to test?

Comment: Please edit your question to spell out the abbreviation "2AFC".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to be able to assert, that two conditions of my task do not differ significantly.

This might sound desirable, but it turns out that failing to reject the null hypothesis in a significance test doesn't give you any evidence in favor of the null hypothesis. So, this would actually tell you nothing.

Assuming what you want to show is that subjects' accuracy was about the same in the two conditions, just compute accuracy for each subject (that is, the number of trials with correct judgments divide by the number of trials) and plot the accuracies of each condition. You might also want to compute a 95% confidence interval for the mean accuracy in each condition, which can be done very easily with bootstrapping.

Comment: Ah yes, of course. That means what you would recommend is e.g. showing the accuracy of each condition plus the response bias?

Comment: No, I don't think there's any need to try to estimate response bias, but it would probably be useful to show the base rate.

Comment: What I'm worried about is this: suppose I have 90% true positive and 10% true negative in one condition and 50%/50% in another. The response accuracy would be 50% in both, but in terms of how the actual response looked like there is quite a difference. Isn't that the kind of question that people would ask if I just presented the accuracy?

Comment: "The response accuracy would be 50% in both" — Only if the base rate is also 50% in both cases. "Isn't that the kind of question that people would ask if I just presented the accuracy?" — It's hard to say without knowing what your study is actually about, its design, etc. You can always add fancier plots or tables if you think readers will benefit from them.

Comment: Ah, yes I meant to add that of course maximum number of possible true positives and true negatives must be identical in my example. Thanks.